# paintComponent() output error

Tags: java, line, paint, shapes, paintcomponent

i'm trying to make a program that will connect two points that i click in my JPanel. i'm trying to connect the two points with a line. i displayed the values of my (x1, y1) and (x2,y2) coordinates whenever i click using the mouse and there is no error in the values. but when the line is displayed, it the line doesn't seem to follow the coordinates i specify but instead outputs in a different location and is distorted. most of the lines will appear to be cut by something, i think it's the rectangle created by the line because i used setBounds(). also, i add a System.out.println("") inside my paintComponent function and i noticed that it printed multiple times (increasing by 1 after every click) even though it should only print once. can anyone help me with this? thanks!

here are two of the classes which contribute to the error:

CLASS # 1:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Arch. Don Saborrido
 */
public class twixtBoard extends JPanel implements java.awt.event.MouseListener{
    int x1 = 0, x2, y1 = 0, y2;
    DrawLine line;
    //DrawLine line;


    public twixtBoard(){
       //requestFocus();
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(false);
        setBounds(0,0,600,450);
        setOpaque(false);
        setFocusable(false);
        addListener();
    }

    public void addListener(){
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (x1 == 0 || y1 == 0){
                    x1 = e.getX();
                    y1 = e.getY();
                    System.out.println(x1 + " " + y1);
        }
        else{
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();
            //System.out.println(x2 + " " + y2);
            line = new DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            line.setBounds(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            System.out.println("" + line.getLocation());
            //line.setOpaque(false);
            add(line);
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        ///throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

CLASS # 2 (Paint Class):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Arch. Don Saborrido
 */
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
//import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawLine extends JPanel{
    int x1 = 0, x2 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
    //Line2D line;
    Stroke[] s = new Stroke[] {new BasicStroke(10.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND)};
    //new BasicStroke(25.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL),
    //new BasicStroke(25.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE,BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER)
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();

    public DrawLine(int start_x, int start_y, int end_x, int end_y){
        x1 = start_x;
        y1 = start_y;
        x2 = end_x;
        y2 = end_y;
        System.out.println(x1+ " " + y1+ " " + x2+ " " + y2+ " ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("entered paint");
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setStroke(s[0]);
        path.moveTo(x1,y1);
        System.out.println("x1 = " + x1 + " y1 = " + y1);
        path.lineTo(x2,y2);
        System.out.println("x2 = " + x2 + " y2 = " + y2);
        System.out.println("" + path.getBounds2D());
        g2.draw(path);
        //line = new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        //if(x1 != x2 && y1 != y2)
            //g2.draw(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: crossposted http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/407781

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very complicated approach.

Try the following:

- make a class (e.g. LineClass) with four variables: x1, x2, y1 and y2.
- keep a ArrayList of your generated lines
- draw each line in the ArrayList on your JPanel using g.drawline(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2) where line is the element of the ArrayList

```
class MainClass extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
  boolean clickedOnce = false;
  ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
  int x, y;
  MainClass () {
    // init...
    addMouseListener(this);
  }
  // more MouseEvent methods
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (!clickedOnce){
      x=e.getX(); 
      y = e.getY();
      clickedOnce = true;
    }
    else{
      lines.add(new Line(x,y,e.getX(), e.getY());
      clickedOnce = false;
      repaint();
    }
  }

  public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (Line l: lines)
      g.drawLine(l.x1, l.y2, l.x2, l.y2);
  }

  private class Line {
    public int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    Line (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.y2 = y2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting the absolute value of (x1-x2) didn't work. it printed a different line. i used the the original parameters (x1,y1,x2,y2) and combined the two classes into one class. now i had a working code. thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
line = new DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
ine.setBounds(x1, y1, x2, y2);
add(line);
```

The basic logic looks wrong to me. You can't just use the 4 values fo the size and location.

The location would be the minimum of the x1/x2 and y1/y2.

The size (width, height) would then be the absolute value of (x1 - x2) and (y1 - y2).

Then when you draw the line you would draw the line from (0, 0) to (width, height).

Maybe the code examples from [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) will help with a slightly different solution.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that you are calculating the width and height wrong. They would be the difference between x1 and x2 and y1 and y2.

You could also probably do this easier using java's Graphics class. That has methods like drawLine(), which would probably make your life easier.